# Convert JS function to Dart

Tags: javascript, dart

I have one small js code to fix one think on iOS devices, but I don't know how to write that code with touchend event at Dartlang. How to convert that js code to dartlang?

JS Code:

```
(function(l){var i,s={touchend:function(){}};for(i in s)l.addEventListener(i,s)})(document);
```

Comment: Good to know; thanks for sharing :) Did you have a question?

Comment: How to write that function on Dartlang?

Comment: See https://github.com/a14n/dart-js-wrapping, https://github.com/atrauzzi/grunt-dart2js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main() {
  var listeners = {
    'touchend': (e) {},
  };
  listeners.forEach((type, listener) {
    document.addEventListener(type, listener);
  });
}
```